# How to handle exceptions when we give no argument to a C executable program

Tags: c++, c, file, exception

I have this C program in which it should be given arguments like the following:

./program -i inputFile -o outputFile

and here's my related section of code

```
  while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "i:o:")) != -1) {
            switch (c) {


                 case 'i':
                          inFile = strdup(optarg);
                 break;
                 case 'o':
                          outFile = strdup(optarg);
                 break;
                 default:

                          error_usage(argv[0]);

                      }
                }
```

also here's the error_usage function:

```
void error_usage(char *prog)
      {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s  -i inputfile -o outputfile\n", prog);
        exit(1);
      }
```

How should I modify my case statement in a way that if I run my program like the following:
`./program` 
it gives me the following error?
`Usage: prog -i inputfile -o outputfile`

Answer (score 2):

Before you call `getopt`, check `argc`

```
if ( argc == 1 )
{
  fprintf(stderr, "... ");
  return -1;
}
```

Comment: And what if only one of the options was missing?

Comment: you can check argc, if argc == 1 when there are no arguments, or argc == 2 if there is only one argument.

Comment: Thank you claptrap. It worked fine. How can I mark this as answer?

Comment: And what if the user repeated the -i argument? Then there would be the correct number of arguments, but the usage would still be wrong.

Comment: then he would need to analyze the results after getopt, but that was not the question.

Comment: What if there were or were not spaces between the options letters and the file names? Then the argc value would differ. My point is that your answer is not an accurate reflection of the requirements, which is to check if an inFile and outFile parameter was supplied. Your answer is essentially a trick, and one that doesn't work as far as I can see.

Comment: Seomtimes the question isn't asked correctly.

Comment: just a question. How to make argv[0] just to show the program's name rather than the whole path? `Expected: "Usage: program -i inputfile -o outputfile\n"
Got:      "Usage: /tmp/tmpj0jOUp/p/program  -i inputfile -o outputfile\n"`

Comment: Then fix the question, @John. Don't blame the answer. GIGO.

Comment: @MonaJalal you would need to copy argv[0] into a buffer and then remove the path.

Comment: Thanks. What I did was using something like this `if ((s= strrchr( argv[0], '\\')) /* get filename w/o .exe extension */
                  || (s= strrchr( argv[0], '/')))
              s++;
        else
              s= argv[0];`

Comment: @john @claptrap When I run my program like ./program a b c d instead of what I mentioned in the question, it tells me something is wrong with the file opening (which is true )but `Expected: "Usage: program -i inputfile -o outputfile\n"
Got:      "Error: Cannot open file /no/such/file\n"`  Do you know how should I handle this? Any clue?

Comment: @MonaJalal i would suggest you write a new question instead of us having a chat in the comment field.

Comment: @john personally I find the best approach to teach somebody is to answer his/her questions at face value, that way the person can continue his/her line of thought and ask more. i find it slightly arrogant to "fix" questions.

Comment: @claptrap thanks for mentioning that. I made it a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18952763/bad-argument-handling-in-c-c

Answer (score 2):

See `inFile` and `outFile` to NULL

Then after your getopts loop check to see if either is still NULL. If they are then print the usage message and exit

```
if (inFile == NULL || outFile == NULL)
    error_usage(argv[0]);
```

Comment: Simply `getopt` can do the job

Comment: @P0W Then you should supply an answer