# Bad argument handling in C/C++

Tags: c, file, exception

When I run my program like `./program a b c d` instead of

```
./program -i inFile -o outFile
```

it tells me something is wrong with the file opening (which is true )but

```
Expected: "Usage: program -i inputfile -o outputfile\n"
Got: "Error: Cannot open file /no/such/file\n"
```

Do you know how should I handle this? Any clue?
Also this is part of my code which deals with bad argument handling:

```
if ((s= strrchr( argv[0], '\\')) /* get filename w/o .exe extension */
                  || (s= strrchr( argv[0], '/')))
              s++;
        else
              s= argv[0];
        if(inFile == NULL || outFile == NULL) {
        error_usage(s);
         }
        if ( argc !=5 )
           {
             error_usage(s);
             return -1;
           }
        while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "i:o:")) != -1) {
            switch (c) {


         case 'i':
                          inFile = strdup(optarg);
                 break;
                 case 'o':
                          outFile = strdup(optarg);
                 break;
                 default:

                          error_usage(s);

                      }
                }

      if (!(iFile = fopen(inFile, "r+"))) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Error: Cannot open file %s\n", inFile);
      exit(1);
   }
```

Comment: Pick one `C` or `C++` I think you need `C`.

Comment: Yes C but I thought they should be almost the same regarding bad argument handling. my bad

Comment: Why do you check `inFile` and `outFile` against `NULL` before you process the arguments?

Answer (score 2):

Well all I can do is repeat the answer to your [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18952077/how-to-handle-exceptions-when-we-give-no-argument-to-a-c-executable-program), which I think was the correct answer all along.

See inFile and outFile to NULL, then *after* your getopts loop check to see if either is still NULL. If they are then print the usage message and exit

```
    inFile = outFile = NULL;
    while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "i:o:")) != -1) {
        switch (c) {
        case 'i':
            inFile = strdup(optarg);
            break;
        case 'o':
            outFile = strdup(optarg);
            break;
        default:
            error_usage(s);
        }
    }
    if (inFile == NULL || outFile == NULL)
        error_usage(s);
```

You placed the check on inFile and outFile in the wrong place in your code. It should go *after* the while loop. What you are doing is checking if the earlier while loop sets the values of both `inFile` and `outFile` and complaining to the user if it does not. And as I said before I don't think `if (argc != 5)` is helpful, I would just delete it.

Comment: If this is a duplicate, could you please close-vote it as such?

Comment: @KerrekSB It's not precisely the same queston, but I think the question was poorly asked in the eariler post. This one is better.

Comment: @john I am doing the same exact thing as you have written above but I am failing on `./program a b c d`  telling me some error about opening the file rather than being guided to calling usage_error function. Any  pointers?

Comment: @MonaJalal I don't see how that's possible, I'm guessing you've made a mistake somewhere else. Could you post the entire code?

Comment: Can this help? `if (argv[1]!= "i")
              error_usage(s); 
         if (argv[3]!="o")  
              error_usage(s);`

Comment: @MonaJalal No that doesn't help for various reasons, 1) the string comparison is done wrongly, and 2) what if the user put -o first and -i second? The code I wrote is correct, if it's not working for you then I think you must have done something wrong somewhere else. But without seeing your code I can't tell what that is.

Comment: @MonaJalal You missed out `inFile = outFile = NULL;`, look again at my code.

Comment: @john it got fixed thanks. I thought if I have ` char *inFile   = "/no/such/file";
        char *outFile   = "/no/such/file";
` would almost do the same. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Getopt doesn't know about "mandatory" arguments. It will parse all the arguments it can find, but it is your responsibility to check the higher-level logic, i.e. whether a consistent set of arguments has been supplied, etc.

Also, you don't generally need to copy strings, since the original string will always be there. The following might work just fine:

```
char const * infile = NULL;

// ...

case 'i':
    infile = optarg;
    break;

// ....

if (!infile)
{
    puts("Error, you must specify an input file. Use -h for help.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
};
```